# Libgdx Android - GL Thread (NullPointerException) & Missing Class File

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

i'm using the LibGdx framework to create a game and I'm using Eclipse 4.4 (Luna). Whilst i'm debugging my application this method is breaking.

```
@Override
        public void run() {
            setName("GLThread " + getId());
            if (LOG_THREADS) {
                Log.i("GLThread", "starting tid=" + getId());
            }

            try {
                guardedRun();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // fall thru and exit normally
            } finally {
                sGLThreadManager.threadExiting(this);
            }
        }
```

inside the `GLSurfaceView` Android class, with the stack trace:

```
Thread [GLThread 232] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
    GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run() line: 1243
```

I know what a NullPointerException is, I know somewhere is passing a null value, but what I would like to know is how can I find out where?

With these types of questions, I can only assume you'll need more code but I don't know where I should be looking, I'll post code from the Java classes on request if anyone has an idea of where I should be looking.

Note: I'm not using GLSurfaceView directly anywhere in my code, I'm assuming it's a library from Libgdx. Unless it's something i'm missing?

UPDATE: Found the issue in detail.

```
GLSurfaceView$GLThread.class [in android.opengl [in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar]] does not exist
```

Comment: Hi, glad you found your problem.  Please put your solution as an "answer", below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

An `AtlasRegion` was being called from the `renderer` class without being assigned a value in the `assets class` hence the null Exception

[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

changing that to a field that is declared solved this problem for me on the code side.

For the solution to the backend issue:

```
GLSurfaceView$GLThread.class [in android.opengl [in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar]] does not exist
```

I downloaded source codes from Google, and assigned the source code inside the SDK folder, `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\sources\`, if you don't already have a source folder create one, put the sources in there and it should reload the class that was being handled. (in this case `GLSurfaceView.class` for API 2.2)

Another way In Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) or any other eclipse I do believe, go onto your project folder right click > `properties > java build path` and assign the source file for `android.jar` in your dependent libraries.